# how to use inheritance scope and isolated scope together

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have html table which is needed to sort.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th custom-sort-one order="'Name'" >Name</th>               
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Name_AAA</td>               
        </tr>           
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So I created my own directive named `customSortOne`.

```
app.directive("customSortOne", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    /// Isolated scope
    scope: {
      order: '='
    },
    template: '<a href="#" ng-click="sort_by(order)" style="color: #555555;"><span ng-transclude></span></a>',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.sort_by = function(ColumnToSort) {
        console.log("ColumnToSort =", ColumnToSort);
        /// Below function cannot be called because it is in isolated scope.
        scope.TestFunction();
      };
    }
  }
});
```

Directive working, when user click `Name` column header, function named `sort_by` know which column is required to sort.
Problem is **it cannot call parent scope's function which is written in controller**.

So I change my directive using [inherited scope](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/).

```
app.directive("customSortTwo", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    /// Inheritance scope
    scope: true,
    template: '<a href="#" ng-click="sort_by(order)" style="color: #555555;"><span ng-transclude></span></a>',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.sort_by = function(ColumnToSort) {
        /// ColumnToSort is undefined which is not what I want
        console.log("ColumnToSort =", ColumnToSort);
        /// Below function can be executed because I changed to Inheritance scope.
        scope.TestFunction();
      };
    }
  }
});
```

Finally I can call parent scope, but problem is **I cannot give value to `sort_by` function as an argument.**

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PqB2OehBFbIVgJtQZX2Q?p=preview)

Comment: why not? you can get needed attributes, and watch it, or even not need watch in yout case if field static.

Comment: try `'<a href="#" ng-click="sort_by('+order+')" style="color: #555555;">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just a bit fix your [link function](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom).

This function have a few parameters: `scope`, `element`, `attributes` and etc.

So, you can just see value for needed attribute

```
link: function (scope,elem, attrs) {
    scope.order = attrs.order;
```

Ofcourse this work for static attribute value, and in this case not needed quotes.
[Updated Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jp8Y8YbSpE6TpgNvL7TK?p=preview)

**UPDATE:** as for first function: you **can** call function from parent scope, just also pass it like

```
<th custom-sort-one order="'Name'" func="TestFunction()" >Name</th>
```

and in directive use [`&`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)

> **&** or **&attr** - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope.

Comment: Thank for complete guidance @Grundy